# df.select('some_col').to_numpy() and df['some_col'].to_numpy() converge to a different result

Tags: python-polars

```
data = {"a": [1, 2], "b": [3, 4]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(df['a'].to_numpy()
[1 2]

print(df.select('a').to_numpy())
[[1][2]]
```

On the one hand it's adwised to not use the df['some_column'] syntax, but on the other hand they yield different results.

Is there a way with polars to say `df.select('some_column').values` like in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`get_column`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.get_column.html) function.  This returns a Series.  (`select` returns a DataFrame.)

```py
df.get_column('a').to_numpy()
```

```
array([1, 2])
```

```
>>> type(df.get_column('a').to_numpy())
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```